Как укоротить следующий отрывок кода Python?
Всем привет, я новенький :) Как можно укоротить следующий код с проверкой возраста для большей производительности? Либо какой способ используется в реальных проектах?
def age_is_numeric(data):
    while True:
        age = input(data)
        if age.isdigit():
            age = int(age)
            if age >= 18:
                print("Доступ есть, удачи!")
            else:
                print("Вы маловат, возвращайтесь позже")
            break
        else:
            print("Не распознали возраст, попробуйте снова!")
            continue

user_age = age_is_numeric("Введите возраст:")



Ввод данных особо нет смысла оптимизировать, в нём основной расход времени - это ожидание собственно ввода. 2) Данный код не работает правильно. Где вообще возврат чего-либо из функции, например? При вводе корректного возраста код опять запрашивает возраст. Из названия функции следует, что она должна возвращать булево значение, а из названия переменной, которой присваивается результат, следует, что функция возвращает возраст. Так что должна возвращать функция?


Да, кстати, нужно заметить, что "укоротить" и "производительность" это две разные цели оптимизации. А можно ещё вспомнить про "читаемость" и "поддерживаемость" кода. Это тоже другие цели.

CrazyElf, с первым понял. Не понял момента с повторным запрашиванием возраста при корректном вводе, программа вроде завершается. "Что должна возвращать функция" весь этот час думал над вопросом, так и не поняв, что имеется ввиду...
Касательно тестирования. Не тестировал, вопрос был создан, т.к я убежден, что это решение может иметь другой вид, более укороченный, читабельный, возможно производительный. Готовых решений загуглить для изучения не удалось, собирал как пазл разные варианты во едино и пришел к этому.

Грубо говоря, я ожидал иное решение от опытных разработчиков с кратким обоснованием почему стоит делать "так", а не как в моем варианте. Если такой подход на платформе не приветствуется, подскажите как стоит задавать вопросы )

@СуннатМуматов А, я не туда посмотрел, извините )  break действительно по обеим веткам срабатывает, но заметить это просто чтением кода не тривиально. Лучше бы там был return с неким результатом )

Вот пример того, как это может быть в реальной программе. Хотя это всё-равно заготовка. Если начать писать классы, то это опять же будет по-другому. Но тут хотя бы метод максимального рефакторинга. Функции мелкие, выполняющие конкретную задачу, и настраиваемые параметрами.
def input_int(prompt):
    while True:
        inp = input(prompt)
        if inp.isdigit():
            return int(inp)
        print("Некорректный ввод. Введите целое число, пожалуйста!")

def is_allowed_age(age):
    return age >= 18

def check_age(age, checker):
    if not checker(age):
        raise ValueError('Возраст недостаточен. Возвращайтесь позднее.')

def validate_age(imputer, prompt, checker):
    age = input_int(prompt)
    check_age(age, checker)

def validate_user_data():
    try:
        validate_age(input_int, "Введите возраст:", is_allowed_age)
        # validate ещё что-нибудь
        print("Доступ есть, удачи!")
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(f'Ошибка проверки данных пользователя: {str(ex)}')

validate_user_data()


Разбивка на мелкие функции, по возможности максимально "чистые", т.е. не зависящие напрямую от других функций, позволяет:

удобно тестировать код
легко перенастраивать логику функций
переиспользовать эти функции
легко читать и понимать отдельные куски кода вне остального контекста программы


Использование исключений позволяет не проверять какие-то вещи по выходе из функций, а "вылетать" сразу на нужный уровень, возможно даже сразу на выход из программы, если не ловить исключения слишком рано
"Говорящие" имена функций позволяют сразу понять назначение функции и возвращаемый ей результат

Легко заметить, что программа получилась не короче, а, наоборот, длиннее. Но её можно при этом:

Легче понимать на уровне любой из функций
Перенастраивать на другой функционал
Тестировать

По-хорошему тут нужно вообще написать класс, вынести константы и т.д. Код маленький, а работы можно ещё много проделать.
